# How to create Checkbuttons with Integer value in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, tkinter

I am creating a project for my college class. I am creating a gui with python tkinter of a pizza restaurant. I have created 5 checkbuttons displaying 5 different pizzas with a different price on each pizza. I have created a calculate button. How can I create a function for the calculate button to display the price of each pizza depending on which are selected? If multiple are selected it would say 'pepperoni price is: $', 'cheese price is: $',...etc? How can I give each pizza a different onvalue in for loop?
Code is here:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('Pizza Restaurant')
root.geometry('500x500')

pizza = [['cheese',5], ['pepperoni',10], ['sausage',15], ['BBQ',20], ['hawaiian',25]]
var_list = ['pizza1', 'pizza2', 'pizza3', 'pizza4', 'pizza5']

for i in range(5):
    button = Checkbutton(root, text=pizza[i][0], variable=var_list[i], onvalue=pizza[i][1], offvalue=0).grid(row=i, column=0)
    var_list[i] = IntVar()


def calc():
    for var in var_list:
        if var.get() != 0:
            label = Label(root, text=var.get()).grid(row=2, column=8)
    
    
    


        
    

'''for e in range(5):
    button_list.append(Checkbutton(root, text=pizza[e][0], variable=var_list[e], onvalue=pizza[e][1],))
    labels.append(Label(root, text=pizza[e][1]))
    button_list[e].grid(row=e, column=0, sticky=W)
    labels[e].grid(column=1, row=e)
total = 0
def calc():
   for i in range(5):
       if i == pizza[i][1]:
           label = Label(root, text=pizza[i][1]).grid(row=1, column=10)
```

'''

Comment: You need to move `var_list[i] = IntVar()` before `button = Checkbutton(...).grid(...)`.  And `button` is `None` because it is the result of `grid(...)`, not `Checkbutton(...)`.  Also assignment to same variable in a for loop is meaningless.

Comment: I got it to ouput the onvalue (price) of each pizza when only one is clicked. How would I do it if multiple were clicked, displaying the unique price of each one?

Comment: It is because you put the price labels at the same position.  You should build the price list first and then create the label with the price list.  Suggest to create the label once and update it inside `calc()`.

Answer (score 0):

How does something like this work for you

```
from tkinter import *

def calc():
    priceList = ""
    for pizza,var in zip(pizzas,var_list):
        if var.get() != 0:
            priceList += ("{0} costs ${1}\n".format(pizza[0],pizza[1]))
    priceStr.set(priceList)

root = Tk()
root.title('Pizza Restaurant')
root.geometry('500x500')

pizzas = [['cheese',5], ['pepperoni',10], ['sausage',15], ['BBQ',20], ['hawaiian',25]]
var_list = [IntVar(root) for _ in pizzas]

for i,(pizza,var) in enumerate(zip(pizzas,var_list)):
    button = Checkbutton(root, text=pizza[0], variable=var, onvalue=pizza[1], offvalue=0, command=calc).grid(row=i, column=0)

priceStr = StringVar(root)
priceLabel = Label(root,textvariable=priceStr)
priceLabel.grid(row=len(pizzas)+1,column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

When you click on each checkbox it will run the calc function to populate the label that appears below the checkboxes. I'm using `enumerate` rather than range to iterate over each item in the pizzas list while still getting an index that can be used to set the row number.
Also using `zip` so that I can iterate over both the pizzas and var_list at the same time.

The calc function isn't too different to your own one, it just adds a new part to a string if a checkbox for a pizza has been selected.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot! How are you displaying the output from the function in a label? I see you have priceStr.set(priceList) then making a label, outputting the text as priceStr variable? What exactly is the priceStr.set(priceList) doing?

Comment: To set text in tkinter you can set the value of a label directly or you can use a StringVar. By doing priceStr.set I am changing the text inside priceStr. When it is changed, any other tkinter widget that is linked to that StringVar with change automatically.

Comment: Okay that makes sense! One more question.. what is happening in the var_list? I understand the first part where you declare it as an integer variable I believe, but what is for_in pizzas doing?

Comment: @Isaiah That's a list comprehension. `for _ in pizzas` means do this as many times as there are items in the variable `pizzas`. So expanding out `[IntVar(root) for _ in pizzas]` to an english statement it means "Create me a list of IntVar objects with the same length as the list of pizzas"